# Unable to compile my android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, build.gradle, android-appcompat

When i try to compile my android project iam getting the following error.

```
  Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
  Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.1/appcompat-v7-21.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.1/appcompat-v7-21.0.1.jar
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.1/appcompat-v7-21.0.1.pom
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.1/appcompat-v7-21.0.1.jar
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.1/appcompat-v7-21.0.1.pom
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.1/appcompat-v7-21.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         SriLankaTemples:app:unspecified
   Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.1/recyclerview-v7-21.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.1/recyclerview-v7-21.0.1.jar
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.1/recyclerview-v7-21.0.1.pom
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.1/recyclerview-v7-21.0.1.jar
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.1/recyclerview-v7-21.0.1.pom
         file:/home/baman/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.1/recyclerview-v7-21.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         SriLankaTemples:app:unspecified
```

Here is my Gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lk.lankahomes.baman.srilankatemples"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.1'
}
```

can some one help me to fix this thank you.

Comment: It couldn't find AppCompat and Recyclerview libraries. Do you have them installed. Make sure you have installed same versions as you say in your file. You can install latest version from SDK Manager which is 23.0.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because the the **21.0.1** **for support libraries** **doesn't exist**.

You can use in `build.gradle` one of these:

```
dependencies{

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

}
```

The same consideration is valid also for the `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7`

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue and installed android SDK build tools -v23.0.1 and referred Android setup guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html#content

but couldn't locate "Android support repository",for latest version of SDK manager- the option is changed to "Local maven repository for support libraries".

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem, but as of 7/15/2016 it's been renamed to "Android Support Repository"

Answer (score 1):

I think the `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"` line is causing the problem.

change it to `buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"`

or try

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

and

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

and yes what sharj has said is also correct, you maybe missing the build tools