# Can't launch app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Using latest version of IDE. Tried with android 2.2 API 10 and 2.3.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:10.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         23.1.1
         23.1.0
         23.0.1
         23.0.0
         22.2.1
         + 11 more
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
         file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
     Required by:
         MyApplication33:app:unspecified
```

Also I can't close my IDE when it builds - it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:10.+')` with `compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1')` in your `build.gradle`. and make sure in the Android SDK Manager that your repositories are up to date (especially Google Support Repository).

Comment: I did what you said, see question

Comment: Could you copy your entire `build.gradle`?

Comment: done - there are two build.gradle.

Comment: Looks fine. Make sure your repositories are up to date, and maybe try with removing the clean task from the build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Please install android support library by SDK Manager.
And Please confirm your dependencies block in build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: doesn't help, the same problem

Comment: Please paste your dependencies block.

Comment: where can I take it ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the right compileSdkVersion on your gradle file. See [Unable to compile my android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664923/unable-to-compile-my-android-project)

Comment: Tried compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'